# Arduino nano 3 - avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

Tags: arduino, windows-8.1, avrdude

I have got an arduino nano v 3.0.

When I tried to install drivers using arduino installation folder, it not shows any driver for nano board. I installed the driver from  FTDI website. 
When i upload the program to board, it's uploaded correctly, but the program is not working. IDE shows the error
**`avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00`**
at console after uploading the program to board.

My OS is Win 8.1 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have removed all drivers available in computer currentely for arduino connecitn while it is connected to computer.

installed this file
http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/CDM/CDM20824_Setup.exe

It worked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for my problem with Nano clone (based on CH340 not FTDI) was to change baud rate to 57600.
Following command line works for me:

```
avrdude.exe -v -P COM3 -c arduino -p atmega328p -b57600 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by selecting the right board that I was using from the Tools Menu. Tools>Boards>Arduino Model

[image: Arduino stk500 getsync]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a nano chinese clone with the 340. The solution for me was to reset the baud rate in device manager to 57600. At first it did not work until I pressed the reset on the nano.  Bottom line baud rate to 57600 press reset before uploading.